# Is there a way to change the shape of my nodes in my networkgraph?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

Right now all my nodes are circles in my highchart network graph.
Is there a way to change these to squares? I have several different types of nodes and I should be able to differentiate them by looking at them.
,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the marker's symbol on the whole series or particular node like in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9oj5cgLs

```
marker: {
  symbol: 'square',
  radius: 5
},
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.marker.symbol